# Dosbox - Ctrl key is sluggish/unresponsive

Tags: linux, keyboard, lag, dosbox

I recently tried Dosbox for some dos-games. However I have noticed that the left-ctrl key is a bit sluggish and sometimes unresponsive.

My Guess is that it is due to it being used by Dosbox as a special key. I tried remapping all the special functions to right shift, but the issue remained.

I guess I could remap another key for ctrl to the applications but left-ctrl is often the most comfortable. Is there another option?

I am using Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

It was my parents computer and everyone had forgotten that there was a KVM switch between computer and keyboard. Ctrl -> Ctrl -> 1 OR 2 changes computer. Removing the KVM switch solved the issue.